# Vectorized alternative to iterrows : Semantic Analysis

Tags: pandas, algorithm, dataframe, numpy, semantics

Hi I'm currently doing a semantic tweet analysis and want to improve my code running time with Numpy Vectorization.

I tried enhancing my code for a while but was not successful in doing so.
Could I just enter the formula within the loop iteration to a function and apply it via Numpy.vectorize?

```py
ss = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

for index, row in tw_list["full_text"].iteritems():
    score = ss.polarity_scores(row)
    neg = score["neg"]
    neu = score["neu"]
    pos = score["pos"]
    comp = score["compound"]
    if neg > pos:
        tw_list.loc[index, "sentiment"] = "negative"
    elif pos > neg:
        tw_list.loc[index, "sentiment"] = "positive"
    else:
        tw_list.loc[index, "sentiment"] = "neutral"
        tw_list.loc[index, "neg"] = neg
        tw_list.loc[index, "neu"] = neu
        tw_list.loc[index, "pos"] = pos
        tw_list.loc[index, "compound"] = comp
```

Comment: Afaik, vectorize does not improve speed of code, as it is sort of a for loop in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over rows in dataframe, you can make use of apply function.

```ss
def get_sentiments(text):
    score = ss.polarity_scores(text)
    neg = score["neg"]
    neu = score["neu"]
    pos = score["pos"]
    comp = score["compound"]
    if neg > pos:
        sentiment = "negative"
    elif pos > neg:
        sentiment = "positive"
    else:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    return sentiment,neg,neu,pos,comp
    
tw_list[["sentiment","neg","neu","pos","comp"]] = tw_list["full_text"].apply(get_sentiments,result_type='broadcast')
```

This should give improvement in perfomance